# Good to share /home with guest Windows in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I mount shared folders in Ubuntu host as drives in guest Windows.

Is it good to share the /home partition or a directory on it which stores all of my  data on Ubuntu with guest Windows in VirtualBox?

1. Will guest Windows work well with the ext4 filesystem of /home? (I
   guess probably yes, since shared folders are mounted in guest
   Windows as if they were network drives?)
2. Will guest Windows's system crush or error or virus remove my data
   on /home, just like it may on its own partitions?

Thanks.

Comment: As much as I like the question, I think SuperUser might be better for it. It's more about how Windows work and what it will do, right?

Comment: As much as I like to ask on superuser.com, I think it is related to sharing between Ubuntu host and Windows guest. Right?

Comment: Both your questions start with "will guest Windows". It's indicating question focus might be more on the Windows than sharing side. I also noted more virtualization questions there on SU. The short answer to your question is "it depends" as there are number of different crushes, viruses and some may touch network drives. As for the safety of shared partition, again, depends. Who has access to guest OS? What runs there? What will run there? Why you shared entire `/home`? PS. I liked your 'pre-edit' answer better. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and do this.  It won't (meaning shouldn't!) hurt anything, but to be on the safe side, you might want to make a dedicated directory for Windows sharing:

In Terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /home/WIN
sudo chown [username]:[username]
```

Then share /home/WIN instead of /home.  That would be safer, and if needed, you can put symbolic links in /home/WIN/ that point to other directories in Ubuntu.